# Why Apache IoTDB reported `too many requests` error and need to restart to be normal?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Apache IoTDB reported an error: `can't connect to node TEndPoint. code: 606, message: Reject write because there are too many requests need to process` and data insertion into IoTDB failed. This error has happened three times in the past half month. After restarting, the system can be back to normal. I use Version 1.1.1 of Apache IoTDB, and set up a 3-node cluster service. Anyone know why this error appeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the accumulation of `wal` log files. There were some bugs here before, so it is recommended to upgrade to the latest version, Version 1.2.2 of Apache IoTDB.